# Is there a way to charge my clients a fee on top of Authorize.net, like Shopify.com?

Tags: paypal, shopify, stripe-payments, credit-card, authorize.net

I am developing a hosted shopping cart service, much like Shopify.com. I would like to charge my clients a fee on top of their payment processor.

Shopify charges 0.5% to 2% (depending upon your plan) on top of Authorize.net fees.

How can I do this?

Stripe and Paypal offer this kind of payment handling [0] and [1].

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees

[1] https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/

Comment: You mean for _using_ Paypal - [just fyi - see 4.5 on _surcharge restriction_](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full#4)?

Comment: As far as I know, shopify is using stripe.com as a platform for shopify payments. Check stripe.com to see if you need any contracts with them to build a stripe wrapper inside of your application.